# How to assign css?

Tags: html, css

I assign the css for the element.

HTML:

```
<div class = "mydiv">Text</div>
  ....
<div class = "mydiv1">Content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mydiv {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Here I want to assign the width for `mydiv1` class inside the class `mydiv` in css. ie) I want to assign the width for 'mydiv2' when it follows 'mydiv'.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Instead of "inside", do you mean you want to select for `.mydiv1` when it appears *after* `.mydiv`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the "condition" you mention in the title? Your `.mydiv1` element is **not** inside the `.mydiv` element. Do you mean you want to set the width for `mydiv1` when it **follows** `.mydiv`?

Comment: yes. I want to set the width for mydiv1 when it follows .mydiv.

Comment: Then please edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
.mydiv .mydiv1 {
  width: //your width
}
```

Comment: But `.mydiv1` is not inside `.mydiv`.

Comment: @Naughty Ninja, I tried this. But the width cannot refer.

Comment: .mydiv .mydiv1 {width: 100px; position: absolute;}

Answer (score 0):

You must change a bit your html. Heres a proposition that makes mydiv and mydiv1 the same width since it's container control it.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}

.mydiv {
  background: pink;
}

.mydiv1 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mydiv">Text</div>
  <div class="mydiv1">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the [sibling combinator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```
.mydiv ~ .mydiv1 {
   width: 234px;
 }
```

This will set the width on the `.mydiv1` element if it **follows** the `.mydiv` element.

Comment: Isnt it enough to just comma separate them? .mydiv, .mydiv1 {width: 234px;}

Comment: @OlivierKrull That would set the width on the `.mydiv1` element completely independent of `.mydiv`.

Comment: Hmm ok maybe I misunderstood the question, i thought he just wants to set .mydiv1 width to the same witdh as .mydiv. The question is not clear.